# Not getting same result on Desktop App than Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, service

I´m having a weird problem here. I´m executing the exact same code on a desktop application than on mi Service App, with different results.

I´m calling a method that query a SQL database. With my Desktop App I get 600 rows when I check the `DataTable.Rows.Count` property. When I do that exact thing with the service, I get 0 rows.
I´m not having any kind of Exception, just 0 rows.

This is the code:

```
    public static DataTable GetAlarmas()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "P_Get_Alarmas";

            resultado = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, query);

            Log.Log.LogError(resultado.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Log.LogError(ex.ToString());
        }
        return resultado.Tables[0];
    }
```

I´ve been doing this from a long time and I´ve never had this problem before. Any Ideas?

This is the procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_Get_Alarmas]
AS
SELECT
    Al.ID_Registro AS 'ID',
    '50' +
    '11' +
    ' ' +
    '18' +
    STUFF(CAST(Ab.id AS VARCHAR),1,0, REPLICATE('0',4- LEN(CAST(Ab.id AS VARCHAR)))) +
    --'E350' +
    Ev.codigoEvento +
    '01' +
    STUFF(CAST(Desc_Zona AS VARCHAR),1,0, REPLICATE('0',3- LEN(CAST(Desc_Zona AS VARCHAR))))+
    '[DC4]'
    AS 'ALARMA'

FROM AlarmReceptor Al 
INNER JOIN Abonados Ab ON Al.Numero_Abonado = Ab.nroAbonado
INNER JOIN Eventos Ev ON Al.Desc_Evento = Ev.descEvento
WHERE Al.informado IS NULL
ORDER BY Al.ID_Registro
```

Comment: what is authentication do you use when connecting to the database? what is the account the service is running under? is it possible that there is more one schema in the database?

Comment: Also what connection string are you using? Does it so silly things like `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: What's in the SPROC? Getting something userbased?

Comment: Also, are you sure your error logging works?

Comment: this is the ConnectionString "Data Source=W2K8-SQLEMCS;Initial Catalog=PacomIs;User Id=sa;Password=sa;"

Comment: It is running as LocalService

Comment: @NicoRiff Could you post the stored procedure code?

Comment: @NicoRiff: I hope "sa" isn't your actual sa password? Not only would it be a very poor choice, you've now broadcast it to the world! :)

Comment: There is the procedure code.